# Recording and replacing variables in a text file in C

Tags: c, variables, makefile

I'm a little stuck on a project which I'm doing. I'm trying to write a function which goes through a text file and stores any variable assignments in a data structure consisting of a key (variable name) and data (variable data). [Here](http://teaching.csse.uwa.edu.au/units/CITS2002/project/) is the project if anyone is interested in having a look.

So far, what I was able to do was to index through the file and identify how many lines contained equals '=' signs, incrementing a variable every time such a line was found and using the variable to initialise a new construct to hold the variables. Here is the code for the function, called *replaceVariables*: (this is not finished yet)

```
struct VarMap {
    char data[1000];
    char key[1000];
};

// Use a hash table to store the variables - variablename : definition
void replaceVariables(FILE* spData) {

    // Initialise the counting variable buffer to hold the file line by line
    int varCount = 0;
    char buffer[10000];
    while (fgets(buffer , sizeof(buffer) , spData) != NULL) {
        // Skip commented lines (preceede by hash '#')
        if (buffer[0] == '#') continue;
        for (int i = 0; buffer[i] != '\n' ; i++) {
            if (buffer[i] == '=') {
                // Increment if line with equals sign is found
                varCount++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf ("varCount has counted %d equals signs.\n\n" , varCount);

    // This will hold the variables
    struct VarMap variables[varCount];
    while (fgets(buffer , sizeof(buffer) , spData) != NULL) {
        if (buffer[0] == '#') continue;
        for (int i = 0; buffer[i] != '\n' ; i++) {
            if (buffer[i] == '=') {
                // Store everything before the first equals sign in the key, and everything after the equals sign as data

                break; // We are not interested if the same line contains anymore equals signs
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Here is the *main* function for context: (it may be important to note here that replacing variables is not the main purpose of the program; the finished program will implement a small subset of the functionality provided by the *make* program)

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char filepath[1000];
    printf("Enter the filepath of the Bakefile or bakefile: ");
    scanf("%s" , filepath);
    FILE* spData = fopen(filepath , "r");
    if (spData == NULL) {
        printf ("Cannot open file.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    replaceVariables(spData);

    fclose(spData);
    return 0;
}
```

My questions are:

**How do I store the variable name and data (indicated by a line with an equals sign in it) in the structure which I have created?**

**Once stored, how should I go through the file and replace all the variables (indicated with a dollar '$' sign before and parentheses around the variable, as $(VARIABLE) ) with their definitions?**

Comment: "`struct VarMap { int data; int key; };`" How is that supposed to hold the names of variables? Also ... values are not always integers?

Comment: @Swordfish Thanks for pointing that out; wouldn't be the first time I make a mistake like that! I created the structure to store the variable name as the 'key', and the variable's 'contents' as the data. My attempt was to make a dictionary of sorts in C.

Comment: Don't forget to rewind the file between the counting and the assigning passes.  Also, in theory, you could have a line of 10,000 characters and you then try to save it into two fields of 1,000 characters each.  If the line is too long, you will suffer buffer overflows and anguish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer th efirst part of the question (I'm not sure about the second part), just a little modification to your code. Replace:

```
   // This will hold the variables
    struct VarMap variables[varCount];
    while (fgets(buffer , sizeof(buffer) , spData) != NULL) {
...
```

with:

```
   // This will hold the variables
    struct VarMap variables[varCount];
    int j=0;
    rewind(spData);
    while (fgets(buffer , sizeof(buffer) , spData) != NULL) {
        if (buffer[0] == '#') continue;
        char *p=strstr(buffer,"=");
        if(p){
            *p++=0;
             strncpy(variables[j].key, buffer,1000);
             strncpy(variables[j].data, p,1000);
             j++;
        }
    }
```

Update:
To test, I added 2 more lines after the last loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<varCount;i++)
        printf("k: %s, v: %s\n",variables[i].key,variables[i].data);
```

./a.out

Enter the filepath of the Bakefile or bakefile: Makefile

varCount has counted 11 equals signs.

k: MK_ARCH_DIR ?, v:  ../

k: CC, v: gcc

k: LDFLAGS, v:  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib  -lNBiometrics -lNCore -lNLicensing

k: CXX  , v:  g++

k: CFLAGS       +, v:  -Wall -I/home/xxx/work/megamatcher/Include

etc...

Answer (score 1):

> How do I store the variable name and data (indicated by a line with an
>   equals sign in it) in the structure which I have created?

Something like this:

```
int p = 0;
while (buffer[p] != '=') {
    key[p] = buffer[p];
    p++;
}
key[p] = '\0';
strcpy(data, buffer+p+1);
```

For the key, we are copying the line one char at a time until we reach the '='. Instead of that, we are putting a null terminator. For the data, we continue printing after the '='.

> Once stored, how should I go through the file and replace all the
>   variables (indicated with a dollar '$' sign before and parentheses
>   around the variable, as $(VARIABLE) ) with their definitions?

You can't replace them inplace as they might have a different size, so you need to copy the file and do the replacement as you go. It can look something like this:

- Go to the first occurrence of "$("
- Copy everything before that to your modified version of the file
- Copy everything from "$(" to the next ")" to a separate string
- Strip the "$(" and the ")" to get the variable name
- Find that variable name in your variables list using `strcmp`
- Append the string you found to the modified file
- Set your cursor to after the ")" and repeat until done

Things you may have to consider is that you have to check for the end of line character. Also, if you use `strcat` to piece together the copy, note that its runtime is proportional to the size of **both** strings. So if you add a variable value to a file, it is going all the way through the file to find the null terminator and append the value there. This is no problem for small files, but for huge files with lot of appending, you might want to write your own string concatenation function that saves the position of the null terminator so it doesn't have to look for it every time.